# Usage of snmpenum

Tags: perl, snmp, exploit, penetration-testing

*snmpenum.pl* is introduced in many materials about penetration testing, although it's already a very ancient program.

I downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/pwnieexpress/pwn_plug_sources/tree/master/src/snmpenum).

And this is the problem I encountered.

```
$ perl snmpenum.pl 192.168.1.36 public linux.txt    # official usage

----------------------------------------
    SYSTEM INFO
----------------------------------------

" is expected in dotted decimal notation..1.2.1.1.1
```

I have no knowledge about Perl. Can anyone tell me whether there's a problem in **linux.txt** or where the real problem lies? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps there is a version conflict between the Net::SNMP module on your system, and the one the author had?
Also, check that linux.txt has line endings that match your system's conventions (ms-dos line endings for Windows, unix ones for Linux, etc).

Answer (score 4):

I've been doing a little debugging of the snmpenum.pl script and the NEt::SNMP is doing fine, the problem is the way the script splits the values when reading the lines from the OID values file (linux.txt, windows.txt, cisco.txt). 
**SOLUTION:**
**If you add a \t at the end of each line in the windows.txt/linux.txt/cisco.txt file the script is working again!**

I've found that if you replace the read OID value by a hardcoded string such as "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5" (or whatever value you want) the Net::SNMP->session.get_bulk_request() query works.

```
my $result = $session-get_bulk_request(){
    -callback         => [\&table_cb, {}],
    -maxrepetitions   => 10,
    -varbindlist      => [$v]
};
```

With the hardcoded strings:

```
my $result = $session-get_bulk_request(){
    -callback         => [\&table_cb, {}],
    -maxrepetitions   => 10,
    -varbindlist      => ["1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5"]
};
```

So I went to see how the var $v is created, and it is read from the file and the code does a split based on the \t char, which is not present at the end of the line. So I assumed the last value will perhaps contain any bogus char ascii code from the end of the line (line feed or carriage return?):

```
while (<CONFIG>){
    chomp $_;
    my @system= split /\t+/,$_;
```

Finally I added a \t (Tab) at the end of the line on the windows.txt, linux,txt and cisco.txt files that are distributed with snmpenum.pl and all worked fine!. For ex with this:

```
 for filename in $(ls *.txt); do perl -i -p -e 's/\r\n/\t\r\n/' ./$filename; done
```

The other solution would be to make a code modification for snmpenum.pl...

Cheers,
Morgan

Answer (score 3):

The files containing the OID's that came with snmpenum (e.g. linux.txt) are in DOS format. Simply convert them to UNIX format (e.g. dos2unix) and it should work fine.